# How to Update in UWP using SQLitePCL

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I want to update all my rows in database but they all rewriting. Here's code:

```
foreach (Details i in details) {
                command = @"UPDATE DETAILS SET Place = '" + i.place + @"', LessonType = '" + i.lessonType + @"', Teacher = '" + i.teacher + @"', Day = " + i.day + @", Week = " + i.week + @", Lesson = " + i.lesson +
                          @", LessonID = " + lessonID + @" WHERE LessonID = " + lessonID;
                using (var statement = database.Prepare(command)) {
                    while (statement.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW) {
                    }
                }
            }
```

How to do Update in SQLitePCL? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, just delete it and insert new row in the table and profit.